# Number field to text in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report, I have a field which represents the "state" and here are the examples:

```
1 = "In progress"
2 = "Withdrawable"
3 = "Requested"
4 = "Paid"
```

So, I am getting a number from db and I want to change the number to the appropriate state text in my preview if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your field is numeric:

```
["In progress","Withdrawable","Requested","Paid"][{table.field}]
```